# How to write long css rules

Tags: css

I know it is not very good practice but when I am chaining not selectors the line is very long. Is there any "continue on the next line" character like for long strings in Javascript?

Comment: Just continue on the next line

Comment: I am talking about situation `:not(.aaa):not(.bbb):not(.ccc)`

Comment: Frankly, if you are chaining `:not` selectors like that I'd suggest you refactor your CSS &/or HTML. That seems extremely verbose.

Comment: That is not my css and html... I am using OpenCMS and I have to style content inside it and avoid styling OpenCMS GUI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet might be to put a comment between the tokens of the selector. Like this:

```css
div {
  color:black;
}

:not(.aaa):not(.bbb)/*


*/:not(.ccc) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">is not red</div>
<div class="bbb">is not red</div>
<div class="ccc">is not red</div>
<div class="ddd">is red</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a way to do like you want, but maybe take the problem in an other way, if you have too many not() you should, create a class for all "not element"

First you have :

```
div:not(#el1,#el2,#el3, ..) {css properties}
```

And then for each element you should put a class
and it will transform your css by  :

```
div:not(.classname) {css properties}
```

Comment: As I have already written I cannot change the markup of OpenCMS GUI and I have to style my stuff inside it...

Comment: My bad i didn't see thecomments below your post.
 It's better to edit your own post with  the missing information. I don't have in mind a way to solve your visibility issue. If you get one, i will be glad to know it.